# select and unselect td inside an HTML table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a table in my website that I want to be able to select one cell and the background color change, then select another cell (not in the same row) and have the first cell go back to the default color while the newly selected cell change background color. I've looked around and can only seem to find stuff that I've already got or something about a bunch of checkboxes. I have a Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/MidlothainAdair/ayqm4x5z/1/).

Here's my CSS:

```
.selected {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4) !important;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Here's my jquery:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
    $("#table2 td").click(function ()
    {
        $(this).toggleClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
    });
    //]]>
</script>

<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
    $("#table tr").click(function ()
    {
        $(this).toggleClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
    });
    //]]>
</script>
```

Here's my HTML:

```
<body>

<table id='table'>
  <tr>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>January</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Second Row</td>
    <td>Still Second Row</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br><br>
<table id='table2'>
  <tr>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>January</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Second Row</td>
    <td>Still Second Row</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</body>
```

I can get `table` to work fine selecting and unselecting rows, but `table2` doesn't work correctly. I select a cell in one row and then select a cell in the same row and it works, but if I select a cell in another row it does not change the first cell back to the default color. The fiddle above shows what is happening.

I tried adding a `<tbody>`, but I don't think that I did it correctly as the results did not change.

I tried adding `$('.selected').removeClass('selected');` and it partly worked. I can select a cell in one row then select a cell in another row and the background colors change correctly, but if I select the first cell a second time it does not unselect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you select siblings for `td` is wrong, Try this

```
$("#table2 tbody td").click(function ()
{
  $(this).closest('table').find('td').not(this).removeClass('selected');  
  $(this).toggleClass('selected');
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ayqm4x5z/7/)

Comment: That did it! I knew I was not doing something right. I've only been working with jquery since yesterday.

Answer (score 1):

It's not performing as you want in table2 because you're calling the .sibling() method, but expecting it to change elements that aren't siblings. The td's in this row:

```
 <tr>
     <td>January</td>
     <td>$100</td>
</tr>
```

are not siblings of the ones in this row:

```
<tr>
    <td>Second Row</td>
    <td>Still Second Row</td>
</tr>
```

Adjust your code inside your click event to something like:

```
$(this).closest('table').find('td').not(this).removeClass('selected');
```

Comment: I did not understand this part of it. I thought since they were in `<tbody>` that they would be siblings. Thank you for the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your header row in `<thead></thead>` tags and the body rows in `<tbody></tbody>` tags and then use:

```
$("#table tbody tr, #table2 tbody tr").click(function() {
  $(this).siblings().removeClass('selected').end().addBack().toggleClass('selected');
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/ayqm4x5z/6/)**

Comment: This is only changing the rows, i want to be able to change the cells in the second table.

Answer (score 0):

Create a css style for the style of your selected cell.

Then toggle that style for each situation (clicked / not clicked) and remove the 'selected' class from the rest of the cells.

CSS

```
.selected {
    color: rgb(252, 69, 69);
}
```

In Jquery when cell is selected ...

```
$(function(){
  $('body').on('click','table tr',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    $(this).toggleClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');

  });
});
```